# Suppose that A and B are $m$ x $ n$ and $n$ x $k$ matrices, respectively. Show that rank(AB) $\le$ rank(B)

Tags: linear-algebra

Where do I start?
HINT: consider the number of linearly independent columns of $B$ and of $AB$.

I got that matrix $AB$ would be a $m\times k$ matrix and that $rank(AB) \le \min(m, k)$ from my textbook.

Comment: How are you viewing matrices at this point?  Are you viewing matrices as linear transformations between vector spaces?  If so, you can view $B$ as a linear transformation from a $k$-dimensional vector space to an $n$ dimensional vector space, $A$ as a linear transformation from an $n$-dimensional vector space to an $m$-dimensional vector space and their product $AB$ as a composition of linear transformations.  Thinking about rank in terms of the dimension of the image of a linear transformation allows for a nice interpretation of the property in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AB : E\overset B{\to} F \overset A\to  G
\\
\text{Im}(AB) = \text{Im}(A|_{Im B})
$$

where $A|_{X}$ is the restriction of $A$ ($A$ from the starting space $X$).

Hence, as the dimension of the image is $\le$ the dimension of the starting space,
$$
\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank} (B).
$$

Comment: I am not familiar with the image terminology

Comment: Simply Im f = f(starting space).

Answer (score 0):

A better hint might be to consider linearly independent rows rather than columns.  How many linearly independent rows does $B$ have?  How are the rows of $AB$ related to the rows of $B$?

Answer (score 0):

By the rank-nullity theorem, it's the same as proving $\text{nullity}(B)\le\text{nullity}(AB)$.  If $Bx=0$ then $ABx=0$, so the null space of $B$ is a subspace of the null space of $AB$.